# Replace html in userscript w/o breaking anything?

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

The below is in my userscript. It doesnt do the alert because when i replace the html i am clobbering it somehow.

How do i replace regular text in a div or span that is literally domain[dot]com so it will appear as domain.com? Well the below works but breaks code running after and other userscripts.

```
$(function() {
    var html = $('body').html();
    var res=html.replace(/\[dot\]/g, ".");
    $('body').html(res);
    //doesnt call, however html is replaced
    alert('a'); 
});
```

Comment: Why don't you query the div or span (`$('span#whatever')`) and change it there?

Comment: @David I havent tried it. Wouldnt that run slowly on html heavy pages? I guess i'll try. `$('span,div')` is correct syntax?

Comment: @David: No good. I get these INSANE spikes. Locks up firefox for 5+sec on target pages. The above solution locks up <1sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the text in the page instead of replacing in the entire HTML. If you get the entire HTML and put it back, that will make it reparse all the code and put it back as it was when initially loaded, whcih means that any events bound to any elements are gone.

Use a recursive function to find the text nodes in the document and do the replacing on the text in each node:

```
function replaceText(node, replacer) {
  var n = node.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i].nodeType == 3) {
      n[i].nodeValue = replacer(n[i].nodeValue);
    } else {
      replaceText(n[i], replacer);
    }
  }
}

$(function(){

  replaceText(document.body, function(s){
    return s.replace(/\[dot\]/g, '.');
  });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ex83P/

As you see, there is no jQuery in the function, because jQuery only deals with elements, there are no methods to deal with text nodes.

Comment: Is this the fastest method you know of? I cant tell how slow this is but its def faster then $('span,div'). I believe is slower then my original but this may be acceptable speed

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a specific set of pages or do you plan on doing this across every page you encounter? If specific, try narrowing down your selectors significantly. This way you're not trying to process every span/div on the page (which is obv slow). Firebug should be able to help you.